Custom log and increment metrics using ErrorHandlingDeserializer
I'm using newest version of Spring Kakfa, 3.1.3, and it seems some recent changes in exception handling is making me confused.
When a poison pill comes in, I just want to log in a particular way and generate some metrics using micrometer. Hence, the poison pill can be skipped and processing continues normally.
To try and achieve this, I'm setting my key/value deserializer to ErrorHandlingDeserializer, and using the proper delegates:
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

This will get me half way there, as I can see the poison pill is dropped as I want, not redelivered. But I still want to log my own error and increment my custom metric. So the question is, where can I do this?
I've tried creating a subclass of org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler and overriding handleRemaining() method but it gets all the records from the poll, so I can't quite figure out which ones failed so I can log and generate metrics properly.
Thank you


I managed to achieve something like you want by doing the following:

Log and skip
I used a FailedDeserializationFunction like this one. You'll have to register it via config - also check the reference documentation
. Note that the FailedDeserializationInfo` that is passed to the function contains detailed information about the error.
Update metrics
To update my metrics (tracking deserialization issues), I updated my @KafkaListener to inject a special header. When I receive any non-null value for this header, I increment a Counter that is injected into my @KafkaListener- something along the lines of this.

Hope this helps!
